# Where 'Kampagne rabat' is set on Relatel?

Tags: woocommerce, project-relatel

Where is this discount set here, called: "Rabat jf. hardware kampagne"?

[image: Where is this discount defined]

Places I've checked:

- If it is a field under the Subscription CPT
- Sale price under the product

Answer (score 0):

It is just the `regular_price` deducted the `sale_price` in WooCommerce.